# branch.io journeys banner close programmatically

Tags: javascript, function, branch.io

I'm new to coding and I'd like to know how I could tweak the following to ensure that my Branch.io Journeys Banner closes automatically after 6 seconds.

This is an advanced optimization feature on Branch Web SDK and I'm not sure where to enter the variable 6 in the following code:

```
branch.closeJourney(function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

More details [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/journeys/#closing-a-journey-programmatically)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to close a Journey after a specific timeout, you will have to implement the timer function yourself. Once, you timer reaches 6 seconds you can make a call to close the Journey as specified in the documentation. i.e. there is no way to enter the number of seconds in the function.